# Passing pointer to a reference to pointer argument

Tags: c++, pointers

I am migrating an old code from Solaris to Linux. I have a lot of functions which accept reference to pointer as arguments such as -

```
static TYPE GetInstrument(const Item*& item);
```

Now, while calling this function I have lots of constructs such as -

```
int test(Item *l_item) {
    TYPE lval = GetIntrument((const Item*)l_item);
}
```

This fails to compile and match the function definition. Any suggestions how should we pass parameters in this case?

Comment: Note you're not "Passing pointer to a reference to pointer argument", you're passing a reference to a pointer to `const`.

Comment: Note that as `GetInstrument` take a **reference** to the pointer to const, it could have side effects such as changing the referenced pointer. Do read carefully the documentation to know *why* if takes a reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: @cppcoder It fails with no matching function for call to GetInstrument(const Item*). Answer from juanchopanza did help to compile this, but I was not sure if it is correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expects a reference to a pointer to `const`, so it suffices to cast to a *reference* of the right type:

```
TYPE lval = GetIntrument(const_cast<const Item*&>(l_item));
```

Where I have used `const_cast` instead of a C-style cast to express the intent more clearly. This would have worked too: `(const Item*&)l_item`.

Comment: are you sure this isn't undefined behaviour if the called function tries to write `l_item` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't think so. `l_item` is a local variable in `test`. A reference to that variable is being passed to `GetInstrument`. But I guess I must be missing something!

Comment: Well, the reference refers to a different type than the variable it is referencing. And it's not top-level const as in `int y; int const &x = y;` either, the `const` is one level deeper. ISTR there is specific provision that this is OK because it says somewhere that `T *` and `T const *` must have the same size and representation etc.